# Python: Replace non ascii characters in a list of strings

Tags: python, replace, non-ascii-characters

I understand there are many non ascii characters questions on stackoverflow but since I'm a total newb I've had no luck in successfully implementing them, plus I find the whole 'unicode' concept difficult to understand.

So I have a list -

```
mylist = ["apple", "samsung", "toshiba", "Don’t know", "Can’t recall"]
```

I would like to access the single quote marks at index 3 and 4 and replace them with an apostrophe.

I tried this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
mylist = ["hello", "don't know", "Don’t know", "Can't recall"]
for word in mylist:
    word.replace(u"’", "'")
print mylist
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Not sure if this is useful but I am using python version 2.x and I know that this problem may not occur if I was using version 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> mylist = ["apple", "samsung", "toshiba", "Don’t know", "Can’t recall"]
>>> [item.replace('\xe2\x80\x99',"'") for item in mylist]
['apple', 'samsung', 'toshiba', "Don't know", "Can't recall"]
```

If all the items are already unicode:

```
>>> mylist = [u"apple", u"samsung", u"toshiba", u"Don’t know", u"Can’t recall"]
>>> [item.replace(u'’',u"'") for item in mylist]
[u'apple', u'samsung', u'toshiba', u"Don't know", u"Can't recall"]
```

Comment: Tried both and I either get an error or this: ['hello', "don't know", 'Don\xe2\x80\x99t know', "Can't recall"] strange.

Comment: @Boosted_d16 works fine for me, don't forget to use this line : `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in your source code. http://ideone.com/HSlDx5

Comment: Had no idea why it wasn't working before but its working fine now. Cheers Ashwini.